# C#: Start process with multiple arguments,any way one of them to be equal to textbox.text?

Tags: c#, process, arguments

Windows Forms application, calling a command prompt from a button.
I managed to pass multiple arguments to it via the following way

```
Process execute = new Process();
execute.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = minusstring; //string equal to textBox1.Text
execute.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
execute.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-log d:file.txt -c ""arg2"" -y ""arg3"" -z ""HOW?""";
execute.Start()
```

What i m asking is a way to fill the -z argument (the HOW? in my code) with the textBox2.Text value, which is filled by the user. The value filled by the user is the path of file in a local drive, lets say c:\Folder\foo.txt

Bear with me and possible stupid mistakes, i just started learning.

Answer (score 6):

I would use String.Format to format the argument string appropriately:

```
execute.StartInfo.Arguments = 
    String.Format("-log d:file.txt -c \"arg2\" -y \"arg3\" -z \"{0}\"",
                  textBox1.Text);
```

You could also just do simple string concatenation which will work fine if you only have one parameter to substitute. If you're going to need something that will scale to more parameters, stick with String.Format().

Comment: Justin's answere is Clean Simple and to the Point.. very nice solution

Comment: Havent tried yet cause the above method worked. Will do just to gain experience. Thank you very much for replying!

Answer (score 2):

execute.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-log d:file.txt -c ""arg2"" -y ""arg3"" -z " + textBox2.Text;

This should work. You just have to do [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a string...

```
execute.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"-log d:file.txt -c ""arg2"" -y ""arg3"" -z ""{0}""", minusstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it something like this assuming textBox2 is in scope

```
execute.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-log d:file.txt -c ""arg2"" -y ""arg3"" -z " + textBox2.Text;
```